# How to format date time?

Tags: xml, date, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

How can I format this date-time in Delphi `WED 16/11/2016 IT 15:26`. This is a value from XML and I want just `16/11/2016 15:26`.

Comment: Add more info about what you want to do and achieve, what have you tried? You have one date string and want same date but formatted in different type?

Comment: This looks quite easy. Have you ever worked with strings before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very simple solution would be to just take the parts that you want of the original string :

```
MyDateString := Copy(XMLDateString, 5, 10) + ' ' + Copy(XMLDateString, 19, 5);
```

Alternatively you may want to parse the original string into a DateTime value so you can better format that value to your desired string depending of the regional settings or whatever you could need at any moment.

```
function XMLDateToMyFormat(XMLDate: string): string;
var DateValue: TDateTime;
begin
  DateValue := EncodeDateTime(Copy(XMLDate, 5, 2).ToInteger, 
                              Copy(XMLDate, 8, 2).ToInteger, 
                              Copy(XMLDate, 11, 4).ToInteger, 
                              Copy(XMLDate, 19, 2).ToInteger, 
                              Copy(XMLDate, 22, 2).ToInteger,
                              0,
                              0);

  Result := FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn', DateValue);
end;
```